Pester Testing Cloud Policy JSON files
I'm trying to evaluate a property inside of a nested property in a JSON document. While there are other properties that exist, I don't really care about them. We're looking to standardize the variables we use for specific things.
I am successfully testing if the value for the parameter exists to have a desired value. that that works as intended. I'm trying to get the anti-pattern where the defaultValue is discovered and then the key name is evaluated. Here's the block for testing that area of the file:
It "Have a standard Effect parameter." -TestCases $testCase {
                Param($instance)
                $instance = $instance | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $instance.properties.parameters | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty
                # Desired Effect Parameters
                $effectParameters = @(
                    "disabledEffect",
                    "appendEffect",
                    "modifyEffect",
                    "deployIfNotExistsEffect",
                    "denyEffect",
                    "auditEffect",
                    "manualEffect",
                    "auditIfNotExistsEffect"
                )
                # Allowed Effect Values
                $effectValues = @(
                    "disabled",
                    "append",
                    "modify",
                    "deployIfNotExists",
                    "deny",
                    "audit",
                    "manual",
                    "auditIfNotExists"
                )

                foreach ($effectParameter in $effectParameters) {
                    $effect = $effectParameter -replace ".{6}$" #drop the "Effect" from the end
                    if ($instance.properties.parameters.$effectParameter -ne $null) {
                        $instance.properties.parameters.$effectParameter.type | Should -Be "String"
                        $instance.properties.parameters.$effectParameter.defaultValue | Should -Be $effect
                    }
                }
                foreach ($parameter in $instance.properties.parameters) {
                    $parameter.defaultValue | Should -BeIn $effectValues
                }
            }

Here's an example block of detail what I'm trying to catch. The description tags (metadata) that will essentially be deleted for my 'production' deployment:
"parameters": {
      "auditEffect": {
        "description": "Desired pattern",
        "type": "String",
        "defaultValue": "audit"
      },
      "auditForExistance": {
        "description": "Catch this bad pattern",
        "type": "String",
        "defaultValue": "auditIfNotExists"
      },
      "listOfAllowedLocations": {
        "description": "Don't care about this variable for testing.",
        "type": "Array",
        "defaultValue": [
          "eastus",
          "eastus2",
          "centralus",
          "westus2",
          "westus3",
          "westcentralus"
        ]
      }
    }

I've tried a few different things. I can't seem to find a way to get into the variable defaultValue to evaluate the key name. The most recent test (in the code block above) doesn't evaluate anything as expected. The foreach block above does capture if the key exists that the defaultValue match as expected.

Through more research and troubleshooting, I was able to do exactly what I had requested. I ended up having to use a hash table and enumerate the keys. Here's the fixed block for those trying to do the same:
It "Have a standard Effect parameter." -TestCases $testCase {
                Param($instance)
                $hashTable = $instance | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $instance = $instance | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                $instance.properties.parameters | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty
                # Desired Effect Parameters
                $effectParameters = @(
                    "disabledEffect",
                    "appendEffect",
                    "modifyEffect",
                    "deployIfNotExistsEffect",
                    "denyEffect",
                    "auditEffect",
                    "manualEffect",
                    "auditIfNotExistsEffect"
                )
                # Allowed Effect Values
                $effectValues = @(
                    "disabled",
                    "append",
                    "modify",
                    "deployIfNotExists",
                    "deny",
                    "audit",
                    "manual",
                    "auditIfNotExists"
                )

                foreach ($effectParameter in $effectParameters) {
                    $effect = $effectParameter -replace ".{6}$" #drop the "Effect" from the end
                    if ($instance.properties.parameters.$effectParameter -ne $null) {
                        $instance.properties.parameters.$effectParameter.type | Should -Be "String"
                        $instance.properties.parameters.$effectParameter.defaultValue | Should -Be $effect
                    }
                }
                foreach ($parameter in $hashTable.properties.parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
                    foreach ($value in $hashTable.properties.parameters.$parameter.defaultValue) {
                        if ($value -contains $effectValues) {
                            $parameter.Key | Should Be $effectParameters
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

Once the block is available, we can use the $parameter and evaluate it's defaultValue for something that's in our list. If there's a match, it then evaluates the name of the parameter successfully.
